# Multiplication of two numpy arrays in Python results in nan values at some places

Tags: arrays, numpy, raster, gdal, geotiff

Apologies for quite a trivial question, I have tried this but unable to avoid this situation. I am opening the two bands of a Geotiff file as numpy arrays(using ReadAsArray), but when I am adding  the square of  two numpy arrays, the resulting array does not consist of all nan values but at some places it is getting padded with nan values

For example, at some place in first array I have value 5 and in second array I have value 174.I am trying to multiply their squares i.e. 5*5+174*174. The result should be 30301 but in the resulting array I am getting nan. At many places the result is nan but not in the whole resulting numpy array. If I import the file in 'float64' format, I am getting the correct result.Here I am not using any functions such as numpy.multiply but just multiplication operators i.e. a*a+b*b to multiply the two arrays

So can anyone advise how to prevent the numpy array multiplication pad resulting array with nan values.

Comment: Add a sample case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The gdal file is very large  around (8000 x 8000 )pixels consisting of two bands. Kindly suggest.